# Replace the specified column contents in the data frame with the values in the specified vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

Here are the sample code

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  B = c(5, 6, NA, 8),
  C = c(9, NA, -1, 11),
  D = c(-2, 13, 14, 15),
  E = c(16, -3, 18, NA)
)

replace_vec <- c(100, 200, 300)
```

I want to replace the column 3:5 which the value is NA or <=0 into the value in vetor `replace_vec`
just like :

```r
df %>%
  mutate(C = if_else(is.na(C) | C < 0, replace_vec[1], C),
         D = if_else(is.na(D) | D < 0, replace_vec[2], D),
         E = if_else(is.na(E) | E < 0, replace_vec[3], E))
```

too much `if_else` and not so general, maybe use `map*` or like

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(3:5, ~ifelse(is.na(.x) | .x < 0, replace_vec, .)))

# or
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(1:3), ~ map2(.x, replace_values, ~ ifelse(.x < 0 | is.na(.x), .y, .x)))
```

they do not work...

How to make the code more general? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
names(replace_vec) <- c('C', 'D', 'E')

df %>%
  mutate(across(3:5, ~ifelse(is.na(.x) | .x < 0, replace_vec[cur_column()], .x)))

  A  B   C   D   E
1 1  5   9 200  16
2 2  6 100  13 300
3 3 NA 100  14  18
4 4  8  11  15 300
```

Comment: Good job! I just read the help of `cur_column()`, still have problem to understand the `current` function, can you explain it more specific?

Comment: @Tenstu May I ask what does `current` means?

Comment: I searched the help page of `cur_column()` and found it belong to the "current" group or variable. It was difficult to wonder how it worked and what is the difference with`df %>%
  mutate(across(3:5, ~ifelse(is.na(.x) | .x < 0, replace_vec, .)))`.

Comment: @Tenstu Oh...That `current` means it calls `.x`'s column name, `across` column `3:5`, `.x` calls column `C`, `D`, and `E`, and for each column, `cur_column()` calls `C`, `D`, and `E`. So, I gave name to `replace_vec` to call by it's name, that `replace_vec[cur_colum()]` calls `replace_vec['C']` for column `C`.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation, it really helped a lot, I may need more time to practice.